# how i can fix url redirection in netlify hosted site?

Tags: netlify

i have hosted a react site on `netlify` but redirect is not working as i want.

You see that here: https://unsplash-app.netlify.com/photo/C6-GjBAOtZc

for example if i go to `/photo/h478dhek` first time it load when i redirect from `netlify` site itself but, when i refresh page it just not work and say page not found. what should i do to make redirection work i want it to be.

i have tried creating _redirects file in my build directory but in official documentation it's not clear that redirection will work in refresh the page

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a single page (React) app, have you tried a [rewrite rule](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#rewrites-and-proxying):

`_redirects`

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

As you mentioned, this file would need to be in your build (deploy) directory after the build.